# Kusto - union + extend with subquery not working

Tags: azure-data-explorer

The query below is giving this error:

'extend' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'traces'

The idea is to do a count of all log messages that start with 'message prefix' that appear between 'start message' and 'end message'.

Here is the query:

```
union
(traces
    | where message == 'start message'
    | project event = 'START', message, timestamp
),
(traces
    | where message == 'end message'
    | project event = 'END', message, timestamp
)
| order by timestamp asc
| extend prev_event = prev(event, 1), prev_timestamp = prev(timestamp, 1)
| where event == 'END' and prev_event == 'START'
| project StartTime = prev_timestamp, EndTime = timestamp, Duration = timestamp - prev_timestamp, DurationMinutes = toint((timestamp - prev_timestamp) / 600000000)
| extend count_messages = 
    traces
    | where timestamp between (StartTime .. EndTime) and message startswith 'message prefix'
    | summarize sum(1)
| project StartTime, EndTime, Duration, DurationMinutes, count_messages
```

It seems to be complaining about the reference to traces following the extend statement towards the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

The error is showing up because you are trying to add the traces table (| extend count_messages...). This would only be possible by joining the table.

I think your idea is to count the number of rows in traces between the calculated StartTime and EndTime. Unfortunately this is difficult in Kusto since you cannot use `| join kind=leftouter (...) on timestamp between StartTime .. EndTime.`

As a workaround, you would need to do a full outer join and then use the statement `where timestamp between StartTime .. EndTime`.

This approach is **not very efficient**. Since you are trying to find sequences, there is a much better way you should know.

It is the **scan**-function.

This function can be used to search sequences in a very efficient way.

A example would be:

```
traces
| extend status = case(
message contains "start message","Startevent",
message contains "end message","Endevent",
"OtherEvent"
)
| project timestamp, status
| sort by timestamp  asc
| scan declare ( anz: int)  with
(
    step s1: status =="Startevent" ;
    step s2: status in ("Endevent", "OtherEvent") 
            and timestamp >= s1.timestamp 
            and s2.status == "OtherEvent" => anz=anz+1;
)
| take 100
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks!